# Server not sending ICMP echo reply

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I'm having a weird problem with a CentOS 6.6 machine. It is a server running KVM and a few guest VMs using a bridge interface. Basically, my issue is this: The VMs on this host have no network connectivity issues at all, I can ssh to them and ping them just fine. The host, however, can pretty much only communicate with devices in its own subnet (including the VMs running on it) and a few switches...

If I run a tcpdump on it and try pinging from a device that can't communicate with it, I can see the ICMP echo requests coming in, but no echo reply is being sent back out. I've checked everything I can think of: restart networking, restart server, iptables is totally empty, selinux turned off, icmp_echo_ignore_all = 0, all routes are correct and identical to other servers in the same subnet that have no issues.

I'm pretty much out of ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this could be a routing issue.  Since the VMs inside KVM can route independently of the host, the issue is not going to be your physical network connectivity, but rather your logical network connectivity.  Check your default gateway and static routes, make sure those are configured properly.  If your host cannot find a route back to the devices pinging it, it cannot respond to icmp (ping) requests.

Comment: Also - try pinging from the CentOS box as well - can you ping your gateway, can you ping 8.8.8.8 (google dns).

If you have managed switches - make sure that the security policy allows more than one device behind the port - some switches will disable communications from ports attempting to masquerade as multiple MAC addresses, since it looks like an un-managed switch is behind said port.

Comment: The odd thing is that the default gateway is exactly what it needs to be and there are no necessary static routes. It has the same route output as the VMs and other hosts in the subnet that can communicate outside of the subnet. If I do a traceroute to something in a different subnet, the host can reach the default gateway no problem, but it just doesn't go past it. I can ping the gateway just fine. Definitely isn't a switch issue though, the port settings are identical to other VM hosts that don't have this issue.

Comment: Any static ARP entries on either the router or the host?  Static arp could cause a disconnect between Layer 2 and Layer 3 (ICMP kinda sits in between, which is why we love pings for diagnostics).

Comment: I guess the thing to consider is your network equipment - which means check for things like ACLs, Static ARP, Port Security Policies...

Comment: Definitely no static arp on the host. Since I don't directly manage the network equipment I'll have to check on that other stuff... I've been told though that absolutely nothing is different between this server and any other one.

Comment: Are you attaching your VMs to your bridge interface, or to the physical interface?  My understanding (which is poor at best) is that you need to have a virtual interface (something like br0:0) and attach the VMs to it.  Don't give it an IP.  It should be bridged to your Host's physical interface.  Check your configs and make sure that the VMs are using the virtual interface and not the physical eth0, or whatever it is on your system.